# Duplicates on Left Join

Tags: sql-server, left-join, duplicates

This is a SQL Server question.

I'm linking three tables from the same database and keep getting duplicate values. Tables REF_Plan_Dictionary and REF_Plan_Assign_Default will produce duplicates on their own because some of the columns will reference multiple sub-options in other columns. Table dev_OUT_MasterEmp will only produce one record per EmpID.

The purpose of the query is to use the M.EmpID and match the information from the other two tables to this piece of information. The duplicates are where the EmpID are repeating several times but all of the information matches only once. Meaning the sub-options I referred to are not showing up since the other two tables are matching correctly. So it's not the matching, it's the fact that the same information is duplicated.

How do I get rid of the duplicates?

```
SELECT M.EmpId
      ,EmpName
      ,[UserId]
      ,PA.Plan_Dict_Id
      ,m.Job_Code
      ,Dept_Num
      ,PayGroup
      ,D.Plan_Name
      ,Plan_Desc
      ,M.[File_Nbr]
      ,[Mgr_EmpId]
      ,[Work_Location]
      ,[Emp_Tenure]
      ,[Emp_Status]
      ,[Plan_Eligibility]
      ,M.[Function_Role_Code]
      ,[Hire_Date]
      ,[Job_Entry_Date]
      ,[Term_Date]
      ,[Dept_Num]
      ,[TeamID]
      ,[CCGroup]
      ,[Channel]
      ,[Organization]
      ,[Hourly_Rate]
      ,[HC]
  FROM [Compensation].[dbo].[dev_OUT_MasterEmp] M
  left join Compensation..REF_Plan_Dictionary D on M.Plan_Id = D.Plan_Dict_Id
  left join Compensation..REF_Plan_Assign_Default PA on M.Plan_Id = PA.Plan_Dict_Id
```

This is an example of my results:
[image]

This is table REF_Plan Dictionary:
[image]

This is table REF_Plan_Assign_Default:
[image]

Comment: Sample data/output would help.

Comment: If you have multiple entries in your mapping tables, you will have duplicate EmpId in your result.To remove duplicate result, you need group you result on EmpId first, then join the result with your Employee table again to add other information.

Comment: @Tim3880 I thought about that. The problem is none of the other tables have an employee ID so I've had to reference other columns to join them.

Comment: You are going to get dupes when there is more than 1 match in the 2 related tables, unless you use an aggregate function, sum, max, etc, or a subquery with top 1 specified.

Comment: So what kind of distinct values do you expect? One row per employee only? One row for per employee per plan?

Comment: @Tim3880 The distinct should be one row per employee only.

Comment: Why does your sql server results screenshot not show all the columns? Is it only duplicating values for certain columns?

Comment: What's REF_Plan_Assign_Default table for and what's inside it? I'm still confused on the relationship between the three tables. I understand the directory table is just names and plan_ids for the plans.

Comment: @NepaliRookie This is just a snapshot. There are a lot of columns and the rows duplicate.

Comment: @Tim3880 REF_Plan_Assign_Default and REF_Plan_Dictionary house information for Plan ID's. The Master Emp table stores information for each employee, including the Plan ID they are attached to. I want to pull in the Plan info and link to the employee for quick reference on what type of payout each employee should receive.

Comment: No, what I was asking was that since you are doing  a `select` on 26 columns, but your snapshot only shows 9 columns. Is it only those 9 columns that has duplicate values? It's really hard to tell where your values starts to get unique.

Comment: Can you post a few lines for you Compensation..REF_Plan_Dictionary  and Compensation..REF_Plan_Assign_Default? It seems (according to your query)  that you don't need the Compensation..REF_Plan_Assign_Default.

Comment: @Tim3880 The screenshots are in my edited post. I still need the PayGroup and JobCode from the Assign_Default. What you provided me below is pretty close! Just need this table as well. I'll play around with it a bit more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the basic plan:

```
SELECT EMP.*, PL.Plan_NAME , PL.Plan_DESC, 
MAP.Job_Code, MAP.PayGroup
FROM [Compensation].[dbo].[dev_OUT_MasterEmp] EMP
JOIN (
  SELECT M.EMPID, MAX(PA.Plan_Dict_Id) AS M_PLAN_ID, 
  MAX(PA.JobCode) AS Job_Code, MAX(PA.PayGroup) AS PayGroup
  FROM [Compensation].[dbo].[dev_OUT_MasterEmp] M
  LEFT JOIN Compensation..REF_Plan_Assign_Default PA
  ON M.PLAN_ID = PA.Plan_Dict_Id
  GROUP BY M.EMPID
) MAP
ON MAP.EMPID= EMPS.EMPID 
JOIN Compensation..REF_Plan_Dictionary PL
ON MAP.M_PLAN_ID = PL.PLAN_DICT_ID
```

please modify the output columns to suit your needs.

Comment: Done! It worked but took a long time to process. Not your fault, of course. I'll give my selections a look and pair them down a bit but this is exactly what I need.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to avoid unwanted duplicate records is to plan out from the start what you consider a duplicate.  In other words, do you want one record per employee id or do you want one record per (employee, user account)... etc.  Once you've determined the unique key to the output you desire, then you structure your query around it by ensuring that when joining on that key that both sides of the join have only a 1 to 1 match.

So for example, assume that you want only one record per employee id.  You can start with your employee table since that is the key of this table.  Then every table that you join to it, you have to make sure only has one record per employee id in it as well.  You can ensure this with sub-queries that contain a group by.  So something like:

```
Select ...
from employees
join
    (Select employeeid, sum(field1), max(field2)...
    from employeedetail
    group by employeeid
    ) employeedetails
```

It looks like in your case you have two types of "detail" tables and your employee record has a foreign key to them.  So if you want one record per employee, then make sure that you only get one record returned for both of your detail records foreign key value.

```
select m.*
FROM [Compensation].[dbo].[dev_OUT_MasterEmp] M
left join
     (
     select Plan_Dict_Id, aggregate_function(field1) as field1... etc.
     Compensation..REF_Plan_Dictionary
     group by Plan_Dict_Id
     ) D 
on M.Plan_Id = D.Plan_Dict_Id
left join
     (
     select Plan_Dict_Id, aggregate_function(field1) as field1... etc.
     Compensation..REF_Plan_Assign_Default 
     group by Plan_Dict_Id
     ) PA
on M.Plan_Id = PA.Plan_Dict_Id
```

In the sub-queries, you have to use aggregate functions on the fields (`Field1` above) because there might be duplicates.  So for example, maybe there is a Payment field and you want to know the total payments that were made to this `plan_id`, then you would use `sum(Payment)`.

Another way to eliminate all but one "detail" record is to filter.  So maybe you only want to see the most recent record.  In that case you would use a filter to eliminate all duplicates but the one you are interested in.  Your sub-query might look something like this:

```
select *
from DetailTable 
join (
    select ID, MAX(updated_date) updated_date
    from DetailTable
    group by ID
    ) MaxRecord
on DetailTable.ID = MaxRecord.ID
    and DetailTable.updated_date = MaxRecord.updated_date
```

This sub-query would return only one record per `ID` and it would be the record that had the largest `updated_date` for that ID.

I can't tell you how you should structure your sub-queries because I can't tell exactly what you are looking to do, but the idea in general is to start with a table or a couple of tables with a join that you can guarantee have a unique key.  Then you can do joins and left joins after that to other tables or sub-queries that also have this same unique key.  You will never have unexpected duplicates again when you master this.

Comment: Is "(field1)" the employee? The other tables do not have employee specific data. One of the only piece of information that links the all three tables is the Plan ID which is duplicated on the other tables.

Comment: I elaborated my answer.  The Field1 in the example sub-queries are attribute fields in your detail tables.